# Односвязный список

Tags: c++

Всем добра.

Написал код с возможность добавлять в конец/начало списка, вывод на монитор и удаление необходимого значения, запись/чтение файла. С последним трабл. Вместо того, чтобы аннигилировать необходимые данные, он стирает также все, что находится после этого самого значения, и с файловыми манипуляциями он ругается, когда хочу считать информацию. Не могу разобраться, в чем причина. Код получился громоздким, так что хотел бы услышать критику на его счет, если возможно как-то его оптимизировать/откорректировать, короче, сделать вменяемым, выслушаю с удовольствием. :) Вот сам код:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo{
int data;
foo*Next;
};
foo *Head=0;

//добавление в начало списка
void add_start(int val){
foo*pt=new foo;
pt->data=val;
pt->Next=Head;
Head=pt;
 }

//вывод на экран
  void show(){
  foo* p=Head;
  while(p){
  cout<<p->data;
  p=p->Next;
   }
    cout<<endl;
    }

 //добавление в конец списка
    void add_end(int val){
    foo*pt=new foo;
    foo*ps=Head;
    while(ps){
       if(ps->Next==0){ ps->Next=pt;
          pt->Next=NULL;
          pt->data=val;
    }
    ps=ps->Next;}
    }

//Удаление искомого значения
void search(int val){
foo*psearch=Head;
while(psearch->Next->data!=val){
psearch=psearch->Next;}
psearch->Next=psearch->Next->Next;
psearch->Next->Next=0;
  if(psearch->Next==0){ 
      cout<<"This list dont have-"<<val;
}}

//Удаление последнего элемента
void del_tail(){
foo*ptail=Head;
Head=ptail->Next;
ptail=0;
}

//Удаление первого элемента
void del_start(){
foo*pstart=Head;
while(pstart->Next){
  if(pstart->Next->Next==0){
         pstart->Next=0; }
  else {
      pstart=pstart->Next;}
}}

//Запись в файл
void write_file(){
foo*pwrite=Head;
ofstream outstrm ("test.txt", ios_base::out);
  if(outstrm.is_open())
    { 
     while(pwrite){ 
           outstrm.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pwrite), sizeof(char)); 
           pwrite=pwrite->Next;}
        }
        outstrm.close();
        }

//Считывание из файла
void read_file(){
int mass[10];
 ifstream outstrm("test.txt");
   while(!outstrm .eof()){
    outstrm>>mass;
}
outstrm.close();
}

int main(){
add_start(3);
add_start(4);
add_start(5);
add_start(6);
show();
add_end(9);
show();
add_start(11);
show();
del_tail();
show();
del_start();
show();
cout<<"/////////////////";
search(5);
show();
write_file();
read_file();
return 0;}
```

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили в свой код отступов - читать этот однородный столбец как-то не слишком удобно

Comment: Учту, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@dil](/users/24806/dil)](/users/24806/dil), в самом деле, функция `read_file()` как-то совсем не получилась. Если бы не словесное описание в начале вопроса, то ни за что бы не догадался для чего она предназначена.

Наверное, она должна выглядеть (по крайней мере) как-то так:

```
void read_file(){
  int num;
  ifstream in("test.txt");

  if (in.good())
    while((in >> num;))
      add_start(num);

  in.close();
}
```

А знаете, код становится значительно лучше, когда функции более универсальны и могут работать с разными данными. Для этого данные, которыми они оперируют, надо передавать в функции в виде аргументов. Тогда, скажем, `add_start()` могла бы выглядеть так:

```
void add_start (struct foo **head, int n) {
  struct foo *item = new struct foo;
  item->next = *head;
  item->data = n;
  *head = item;
}
```

и использоваться в обновленной `read_file` вот так:

```
/*
  Записывает числа из файла <fname> в список <list>
  Возвращает false при ошибках
*/
bool readfile (const char *fname, struct foo **list) {
  ifstream in(fname);

  if (!in.good()) {
    cerr << "Can't open " << fname << '\n';
    in.close();
    return false;
  }

  int n;
  while ((in >> n)) 
    add_start(list, n);

  bool rc = in.eof(); // если дошли до конца файла, то все ОК, вернем true    
  if (!rc) {          // какая-то ошибка при чтении очередного числа
    in.clear();       // сбросим флаг ошибки для попытки чтения нечисловых данных
    string s;
    in >> s;
    if (in.good())
      cerr << "invalid data: [" << s <<  "] in file: " << fname << '\n';
    else
      cerr << "file: " << fname << " read error\n";
  }

  in.close();
  return rc;
}
```

Остальные функции стоит также переделать, чтобы они могли работать с разными списками. Если функция *может* изменить указатель на начало списка (как это делает `add_start()`), то в качестве списка ей надо передавать адрес указателя (часто говорят указатель на указатель).

Если же функция не меняет список, то можно передать адрес элемента списка. Например:

```
void show_list (struct foo *list) {
  for (; list; list = list->next)
    cout << list->data << '\n';
}
```

Кстати, обратите внимание, в таком виде у функции появилось новое свойство. Теперь она может печатать список не только с начала, а с любого (очевидно, найденного ранее) элемента.

Теперь все переменные можно "загнать" в  `main` и она  может выглядеть так (делаем 2 списка из 2-х файлов)

```
int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  struct foo *head_list1 = 0, *list2 = 0;

  if (read_file(av[1] ? av[1] : "test.dat", &head_list1))
    show_list(head_list1);
  else
    cout << "Fail\n";

  cout << "---\n";

  if (read_file("test.txt", &list2))
    show_list(list2);
  else
    cout << "Fail\n";

}
```

Что касается остальных функций, то (критики много, времени мало) посмотрите внимательно на то, что у Вас возможны операции доступа по НУЛЕВОМУ указателю. Просто сейчас Вы неявно предполагаете, например, что `search()` всегда будет вызываться для непустого списка (а это может быть не так).

Также проверьте, что произойдет, если удаляя хвост Вы удаляете единственный элемент в списке или удаляя искомый, удаляете первый (тот, на который указывает head). В таких случаях значение head (указателя на список) тоже необходимо менять.

В общем, переработайте (с учетом списка, как параметра функций) и если будут еще вопросы, то не стесняйтесь, задавайте (IMHO лучше новой темой, которая может в своей преамбуле ссылаться на эту).

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, буду разбираться с кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый dil . По моему не слишком большому опыту следует по возможности избегать типовых преобразований при помощи оператора приведения типов "reinterpret-cast", который Вы использовали в функции "Записи в файл". Кстати, при записи и чтении файлов такое приведение типа особенно опасно.
И ещё. При удалении элементов из списка удобней сделать так, чтобы удаляющие функции просто возвращали значение удалённого элемента, а не принимали в качестве значений имена переменных которым эти значения следует вернуть.
Удачи.